I'm doing my project work on astrophysics. So what i want to find how much black hole grows over time
So problem in the code I have to find the velocity of gas that falling in the black hole at the point of event horizon,from this i can find the increasing $dm$ mass from Bondi equation over $dt$ time. Obviously we make a mistake a mistake that's from using Newtonian mechanics the velocity of gas acceding the value of speed of light. So I have to use general relativity. So I have no idea how to do that and I searching the material that I can find useful and how to solve this problem.

https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.03579 and https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.03704 might be helpful.

Might this be something you ought to discuss with your advisor?

"I searching the material that I can find useful" - Have you thought of searching the web? http://astro.vaporia.com/start/bondiradius.html
